# LESS not compiling

Tags: css, html, less

This is my first attempt at writing some LESS css code and I can't seem to get it to compile. I'm sure I'll be missing something simple but I can seem to find what it is.

My Styles are declared as follows:

```
<!--Styles & JS-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sniglet' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="css/theme.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"/>
```

And my LESS file looks like this:

```
//Theme Colours
@headingcolor: #212d43;
@accentcolor: #005bc4;
@textcolor: #FFF;
@footercolor: #0856a1;

//Theme Fonts
@font: 'Sniglet', cursive;

//Theme Sizes (1980)
@mainfont: 12px;
@h1: @mainfont + 6;
@h2: @mainfont - 1;
@footerlinks: @mainfont - 2;

//Styles
header {
    background: @headingcolor;
    color: @textcolor;
    font: @font @mainfont;
    padding:10px 36px 15px 36px;
}
```

Comment: what do you use to compile it?

Comment: Client side - so using the CDN JS file

Comment: what's the link to the CDN JS file?

Comment: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.min.js"></script>

Comment: LESS is for development, you need to compile it to css in production

Comment: You forgot to include the less js files on the page, it is not known and compiled by browsers. Either that or you need to compile it to css and reference the resulting .css instead. @AlonEitan no, not neccessarily.

Comment: I'm using <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.min.js"></script> to complile and loading it after the .less file

Comment: Have you defined the webserver to support less file extension with the correct mime type? google "less mime type apache/iis"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load your stylesheet before the js. With your `theme.less`, the following code is working:

```
<body>
    <link href="css/theme.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"/> 
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.min.js"></script>

    <header></header>
</body>
```

If everything is working, you should find in your browser console some messages like:

```
less.min.js:13 rendered http://localhost:8000/theme.less successfully.
less.min.js:13 css for http://localhost:8000/theme.less generated in 19ms
less.min.js:13 less has finished. css generated in 20ms
```

Comment: I'm loading the JS at the bottom of the body so it's already after the .less file and still not working

Comment: You can find a working minimal example with your code here: http://jsbin.com/bavobitutu/edit?html,output - Do you have any output in your console?

Comment: Nope no output - it's almost as if the JS is not being run

Comment: Just be sure to give all the right permissions to your webserver, I wonder if it can read the .less file. Did you also add a `<header>` element to your markup?